# xsl is there a way to generate a unique id for containing element and get it to the javascript

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Find the following line below in the xsl:

```
var tdElem = document.getElementById('???') <!-- Would like to get td here, if possible -->
```

Is it possible to generate a unique id for the containing td and concat that into my javascript function?

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: 'can_be_any_color_here'">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                <script>
                  var tdElem = document.getElementById('???') <!-- Would like to get td here, if possible -->
                  var bgColor = tdElem.style.backgroundColor;
                  var textColor = mycolorcontrastfx(bgcolor);
                  tdElem.style.color = textColor;
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="blackorwhite.xslt"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
  </cd>  
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate-id` to generate a unique ID for an XML node

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="concat('CDTableCell', generate-id())" />
```

Or, in this particular case, you make do with using just the position of the `cd` selected

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="concat('CDTableCell', position())" />
```

To assign the id to the `td` node, you can use Attribute Value Templates

```
<td id="{$id}" style="..." />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
          <script>
              function mycolorcontrastfx(bgColor)
              {
                return '#000000';
              }
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
              <xsl:variable name="id" select="concat('CDTableCell', position())" />
              <td id="{$id}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                <script>
                  var tdElem = document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="$id" />') 
                  var bgColor = tdElem.style.backgroundColor;
                  var textColor = mycolorcontrastfx(bgColor);
                  tdElem.style.color = textColor;
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does not `generate-id()` guarantee to generate an ID for each argument node that is unique among all those it could or would generate for any input node during the same application of the stylesheet?  In that case, what purpose do you have in mind for prefixing the generated ID with `'CDTableCell'`?

Comment: The only reason I added the prefix to give the id a sort of meaningful name, to make it clearer what it was for. In theory though, if the XSLT had a second `xsl:for-each` on the `cd` elements for some reason, then `generate-id()` would generate the same IDs for them.